# Can't detect scroll event since Chrome update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I just updated Chrome Mac to v41.0.2272.101 and realized that I was now unable to detect JavaScript scroll event on window when my full-screen element has overflow: hidden. Don't know why it used to work a few days ago, but I just didn't touch my code since the update.
Weird thing is: it works on Safari.

I created a simple Fiddle to show you: https://jsfiddle.net/4cd2uf0c/3/

Example:

```
<div class="scroll-div"></div>

.scroll-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    alert('This used to work before on Chrome Mac');    
});
```

Any ideas or workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should report it as bug, usually dev team fixes it quickly: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Is working for me - Version 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit)

Comment: Shot in the dark because I dont have chrome on a Mac to test it but if @ajmajmajma says it works, are you sure you didnt click that little "dont allow this page to display any more messages" on the alert box? Ive done that before when using alerts to debug and thought the code was broken.

Comment: @DasBeasto I didn't click that box, i'm using alert here just for the example and the Fiddle. I normally use console.log to debug.
Btw, thank you all for your answers. I found a temporary workaround: the 'wheel' event. Hope it will do the trick !